# Using Linked List in Hazelcast

Tags: java, in-memory-database, hazelcast

I was just wondering if I could use Linked List as a data structure in Hazelcast because my requirement demands this. At present there is only Distributed Map , Distributed Queue , Distributed Set and Distributed List only. If possible how do I implement it ?

Comment: Why not using distributed queue? What is it missing?

Comment: Can a doubly linked list logic be implemented in Distributed Queue? @TalipOzturk

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is 'just' some Objects of the form

```
class Entry
{
    Entry next;
    Object value;
}
```

and an Object 'the list' that manages those.

Doubly linked list of course adds

```
class Entry
{
    Entry next;
    Entry previous;
    Object value;
}
```

So if you use a 'Distributed Set' and put in objects of type Entry, you can 'add' linked list features on top of any Collection implementation, which of course would require you to implement the managing 'the list' as well.

But I cannot tell if something like this makes sense in your case.